# Defining numbered indexes of an array retrieved by PDO

Tags: php, arrays

In short - I have two tables.

One generates me the simplexml_loadfile method, the second is the PDO query. I need to compare both of them, after the first one (downloaded by simplexml) I'm passing foreach and I get indexes of type `$xml['element']`, while in the same loop I need to further define the elements of the collection retrieved from the database.

The result of the query from the database is written to the variable `$db` and in the loop after the XML defines it as `$db['element']` although it is an undefined element because the array has indices counting from `0` to `n`.

The only way I can think of is to use another for loop, or foreach to pass through the records of the second array, but I would avoid that. Is there any other way?

```
$db = $stmt->fetchAll();
$XML = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xmlarray = $XML->products->product;

foreach ($xmlarray as $xml) {
    echo $xml['element']; // It works
    echo $db['element']; // Isn't works
    echo $db[0-n]['element']; // It works
}
```

Comment: Also share your `file.xml` and expected output.

Comment: It does not make sense to include this file, even if it is too large and does not help at all. What result do I want to achieve described in the post. More specifically - I want to get to the $ db records without using an extra loop

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Show a small sample of the file and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: instead of using foreach try while

Comment: You can't have `$` before `foreach` and you need `;` at the end of the `echo` statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the corresponding elements of the two arrays, you can do:

```
foreach ($xmlarray as $i => $xml) {
    echo $xml['element'];
    echo $db[$i]['element'];
}
```

Comment: There is a problem that these two tables have a completely different structure. Your method is okay, but in my case I get an undefined index

Comment: That's why we asked for some sample input and output. Otherwise we just have to guess what you mean. What is the relationship between the DB and XML?